# Create single node if select single node is null

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmlnode, selectsinglenode

I have a program that updates a config file.  For example, the config file may contain:

```
<configuration>
  <userSettings>
    <setting name="phoneNumber" serializeAs="String">
      <value>123-456-7890</value>
    </setting>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

To update this config file, I use the following:

```
XmlNode phoneNumberNode = theConfig.SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings/setting[@name='phoneNumber']");
phoneNumberNode.FirstChild.InnerText = this._cloudPublisherWebURL;
```

Now, during the update I want to update phoneNumber and address.  Address *may or may not be* in the config file.

If SelectSingleNode is null, I would like to create a node with the given path and set its value.

```
XmlNode addressNode = theConfig.SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings/setting[@name='address']");
if(addressNode == null)
{
  //..Create the node here
}
```

How can I create the node with value at the given path?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508390/create-xml-nodes-based-on-xpath/509340#509340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlNode addressNode = theConfig.SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings");
XmlNode setting = addressNode.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings/setting[@name='phoneNumber']");

setting.SetAttribute("name", "address"); //this is to change the name attribute value into address
```