# How to use Xpath to insert into xml files

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xpath, .net-2.0

```
<feed>
    <entry>
        <data>1234</data>
        <content>Stackoverflow</content>
    </entry>
</feed>
Next data..
```

I have to create above xml using xpath in c# is this possible to do..

I had done xml file using below code

```
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Log_Data.xml");

        XmlElement newelement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("entry");
        XmlElement xmldata = xmlDoc.CreateElement("data");
                    XmlElement xmlcontent = xmlDoc.CreateElement("content");

                    xmldata.InnerText ="1234" ;
        xmlcontent.InnerText ="Stackoverflow";

                    newelement.AppendChild(xmldata);
        newelement.AppendChild(xmlcontent);

                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);
        xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Log_Data.xml");
```

but i have to use Xpath like we do in sql to write queries like
"**Insert into table............."**
should it possible in .Net 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XPath is a *query* language for XML documents. As such, it doesn't provide the capability to alter (delete or insert nodes)  an XML document**.

One of the most appropriate ways to create or alter an XML document (called XML transformation) is to use XSLT -- a language especially designed for XML transformations.

From C# one can use the .NET **[XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)** class to perform any XSLT 1.0 transformation.

Third party .NET implementations exist for XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `XPath parser` to achieve this. Simple implementation of that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508390/create-xml-nodes-based-on-xpath).

Comment: if i create xpath then it should remove concurrency means at a time two process write the file then i have to avoid process exception

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508390/create-xml-nodes-based-on-xpath