# How to create XmlNodes structure based on certain pre-condition

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, xmlnode

What I'm trying to do is create an XmlNode at a specific path if it doesn't exist.

My function looks like this:

```
public XmlElement getElement(string path) 
{
    XmlElement result = (XmlElement)document.SelectSingleNode(path);
    if (result == null) {
        // TODO: Create the specified path here
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any built-in function I can use to create the element at the specified path? The path might contain attributes like this `/root/element[@id="5"]/subelement/item[@name="thing"]`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Essentially you want to create nodes from the XPath query.  There is a discussion of that on this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508390/create-xml-nodes-based-on-xpath](question).  Essentially, it is isn't totally doable, but if you make some assumptions or restrictions, you can do it partway.

Comment: Are you trying to create the whole xml structure based off the xpath or just an attribute?

Comment: @diaz994 Yeah I'm trying to create the whole xml structure