# Build XML using XPATH - C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306863/java-build-xml-document-using-xpath-expressions) does anyone knows about some C# framework doing similar like dom4j do?
I need to build up XMLs using XPATHs.

Comment: I thought XPATH was for searching in existing XML streams and plucking out values, not "building up" new ones.  I'd be shocked if C# didn't already have such a thing.  It's likely to be just one, instead of the many alternatives available to Java (e.g., dom4j, jdom, etc.).

Comment: Not XPath expression related, but some sort of XPath engine implementation question. Retagging

Comment: Recommendation requests are, in general, off-topic for stack overflow.  But does [Create XML Nodes based on XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/508390/3744182) answer the question of the person awarding the bounty?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for XPath natively part of C# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath?view=net-6.0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30800850)

Comment: well the answer is really in the "natively" + consult the documentation of your language provider to get precise info, not much more to say than you don't need to look further than the libraries provided in C#.Net API, dom4j is not native in Java but System.XML.Xpath is native to C#