# how to update xml using xPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax, stax

i have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="25779111" lat="50.03342" lon="5.461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="50.03304" lon="5.814"/>
<node id="25779119" lat="50.03395" lon="5.8255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<ele k="maxspeed:zone" v="60"/>
```

and i reviewed some posts to know how can i update or change a value in the xml file using xpath, and  idid the following :

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 2; i++) {
    String expr0 = "//node[@lat='53.0334062'][@lon='8.8461545']/following-sibling::tag["+i+"]/@v";
    xPath.compile(expr0);
    Node s = (Node) xPath.evaluate(expr0, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(s);

    s.setNodeValue("999");
}
```

but when i checked the xml file, i expected to see the change written to it, but there was no change.
please let me know how to change the value in the xml file using xPath correctly.

Comment: Maybe this post could help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124239/how-to-update-xml-using-xpath-and-java

Comment: Did you write the file back to disk? Otherwise, it sounds like you only modified the DOM (in-memory representation of the document).

Comment: @FatalError can u give me an example how to write that value back on the file using xpath?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the document back to the disk. Here's how:

```
  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
  String filePath = "path/to/new/file.xml";
  StreamResult streamResult =  new StreamResult(new File(filePath));
  transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
```

More help here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT4.html

Hope this helps. :)