# How can I get a specific node from XML in Java and then remove it?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have an XML file that I need to navigate and it's something like this (full XML is [here](https://gist.github.com/Echatl/3914456161ac8e7e1981de4cba30b796)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<md:EntitiesDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" ID="_id-83bbfdd3-e4c4-42cf-a024-e4733569a4ae" entityID="https://id.eht.eu">
        <md:Organization>
            <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="it">EtnaHitech</md:OrganizationName>  
            <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">EtnaHitech</md:OrganizationName>   
            <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="it">EHT</md:OrganizationDisplayName>     
            <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">EHT</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
        </md:Organization>
    </md:EntityDescriptor>
    <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" ID="_gh3s48d19e23e85be40k4ab5ey331e7k4f04f73fb5" entityID="https://id.lepida.it/idp/shibboleth">
        <md:Organization>
            <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="it">Lepida</md:OrganizationName> 
            <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="it">Lepida</md:OrganizationDisplayName>   
        </md:Organization>
    </md:EntityDescriptor>
</md:EntitiesDescriptor>
```

Let's say I want to get the node/element `md:EntityDescriptor` with a specific value of the attribute `entityID`, like for example `entityID="https://id.eht.eu"`

I tried to use XPath with Java, and this is my code:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("C:/outputTest/input.xml");

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//md:EntityDescriptor[@entityID='https://id.eht.eu']");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

And when I try to cycle on the result:

```java
if (nl != null && nl.getLength() != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

my `NodeList` is always empty. I can't get this thing to work. I expect it to at least get the specified node in my `NodeList` and then I'll try to remove it entirely from the document. In general, I need to make something that will get any node `md:EntityDescriptor` with a specified value of `entityID` and then remove it from the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is using [*namespaces*](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/). Querying such documents with XPath is slightly different - [XPath with namespace in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13702637/6367213). Using the knowledge from the linked question, the simplest way to adapt your code would be to edit your XPath like this:

```
//*[local-name()='EntityDescriptor'][@entityID='https://id.eht.eu']
```

Next, you said you wanted to *remove* ([Removing nodes from an XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20611/6367213)) elements that are the result of your search query. You could do so by iterating your `nl` one `Node` at a time, refer to its parent, and have it remove the reference to that node. Adapting your own code, this process could look like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Node elem = nl.item(i);
    // Debug output:
    // System.out.println(elem.getTextContent());
    elem.getParentNode().removeChild(elem);
}
```

Finally, you probably want to *store* ([How to update XML using XPath and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6124239/6367213)) your modified document. You can do something like this:

```java
Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
xformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File("C:/outputTest/output.xml")));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the edits and the insights. The only thing I was missing was the correct XPath to navigate the document, with this method I can make this work.

Comment: Excellent answer.  But w3schools is, well, awful.  Perhaps https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/ would be a better link for XML namespaces?