# How to handle XML in Java with a simple access to the nodes?

Tags: java, xml

What best meets my requirements in creating and modifying XML?

Requirements:

- checking whether a node exists through the entire path from the root

  ```
  <root>
     <a>
        <b>
        </b>
     </a>
  <root>
  ```

  `-> //root/a/b`
- creating XML nodes with easy access to them, like expressions in [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

What can be recommend?

Comment: You may write a simple helper class to accomplish your task around DOM. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346867/851432

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java XPath API in `javax.xml.xpath` package. This is a tutorial

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

And to create XML nodes using XPath check this out

- [Create XML Nodes based on XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508390/create-xml-nodes-based-on-xpath)
- [JAVA: Build XML document using XPath expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306863/java-build-xml-document-using-xpath-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is overkill for you but [XmlBeans](http://wiki.apache.org/xmlbeans/XmlBeansFaq) from Apache is pretty cool and [JAXB with Binders](http://www.devguli.com/blog/eng/jaxb-binder-and-xpath/) (which is perhaps a bit more modern) are both great options for modelling strictly defined XML (those with XSD Schema, DTD) in a Java friendly manner as simple beans. With a little extra coding, both can use XPath to reference elements within the XML data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Groovy, `XmlSlurper` plays nicely with Java, e.g. [reading](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper) and [updating](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Updating+XML+with+XmlSlurper). Groovy has its own expression language [GPath](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GPath), which has similar purpose as the more well-known `XPath`.

Curious for more? Visit [Groovy XML processing](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML).